# How do you calculate if a number is a multiple of another number(well sort of)

Tags: c#

Please i'm in a bit of fix. I have a number, say 9 and i would like to figure out how to write a program to calculate if an unknown number is maybe 21(ie 9+12) or 30(i.e 9+12) and so on

Comment: 21 and 30 are not multiples of 9

Comment: I advise you to restate and expand question, or it will be closed soon.

Comment: Write a program in what?  You have C# and SQL tags....  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Why is that question tagged `sql-server`? You want to do that in SQL or C# or just plain ol' MATH?

Comment: What? C#, SQL-Server, 9, 21, and 30? I think we need a bit more too go on.

Comment: I just took the liberty to remove the sql-server tag

Comment: I have no idea what the question is really about but i worked on a project to resolve functions for certain numbers using genetic algorithm, might be to much but i'll dump it here anyways - http://functionresolver.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Aleadam take liberty and remove C# and add homework ;)

Comment: @Andrew lol I did not even think about it :P

Answer (score 9):

Use the % operator and check if the result is 0 (multiple) or not zero (not multiple)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer for multiples...although the question is horribly asked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Aleadam is correct but the link appears to have broken. Putting a little more context

The % Operator will find the mathematical remainder so if the numbers are multiples the remainder will be 0

% Operator is the following format

```
dividend % divisor
```

For example

SELECT 9%3 will return "0" because 9 is a multiple of 3

SELECT 7%3 will return "1" because 3 does not go into 7 and instead has a mathematical remainder of 1/3

```
SELECT 7 / 3 AS Integer, 7 % 3 AS Remainder;
```